# Making 2 button display side by side

Tags: html, authentication

[image: mySITE]

I need to make this Login and Cancel button to sit side by side to each other.

I also need to have a picture of a lock to my login button..

Please help...

Here's my code so far:

```
<div class="container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username???" name="uname" required>

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me

</div>
```

Comment: What does your css look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in here

Use `form-group` class , and awesome icon

https://plnkr.co/edit/RNjeqen9BED2hY1hWDRq?p=preview

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you..I will check this later on...Need to step away from my computer.

Comment: @DylanMecagami okay , if you can post img you want help in btn , i can use it insteed use font awesome . And if it helpful for you , please accept for me ^^